# How to port forward on Genexis Platinum 4410?

Tags: networking, router, firewall, port-forwarding

I have checked [portforward.com](https://portforward.com/) but it does not have anything regarding this router.

I have searched the router console, but could not find anything other than inbound firewall rules(is that the same as port forwarding).

I have scrubbed the internet for manuals or any guides related to this router but nothing. All the other routers which I have used always had an option to port forward in the console, so I thought this would be the same.

Is it possible that this router does not support port forwarding?

P.S. Can't change the router as it's provided by the ISP

Comment: Most likely your ISP has installed customized firmware, that explicitly disables port forwarding. This is not unusal for residentail lines provided by low-quality ISPs, as it reduces attack surface and thus support load on the ISP

Comment: Have you tried contacting Genexis directly?

Comment: I contacted my ISP and said port forwarding is available on my router but the technicians are unable to tell me how?

Also I have contacted Genexis directly and am waiting for their reply

Answer (score 5):

Login to the router. (192.168.1.1 in my case)

Go to *APP* → *Advanced NAT* → *VirtulaServerConfiguration*. Select "*Customize*" if using for a custom purpose. If using for some standard application, select "*Select Application*".

```
Interface      : connection name
Protocol       : tcp or udp
SourceIpAddress: The public IP visible in the internet
StartPortNmber : from which port number it will be mapped
EndPortNumber  : till which port number it will be mapped
InternalHost   : private ip of the host system(preferably static IP)
MappingName    : just an identifier
```

Click "*Add*" to enter the details to the table.  "*Enable*" in the table will be set as open.

Example of the data entered:

[image: Example of the data entered is shown here]