# How do I port forward on a Genexis Platinum 4410?

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

According to [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1415011/how-to-port-forward-on-genexis-platinum-4410), I have to set up some stuff in order to port forward. But I don't know what to put in any column.

I don't have a static IP address if it helps. I've set up port forwarding on one other router but it wasn't this confusing.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Context: I'm trying to run a Minecraft server on my computer. I've not set static IP yet. I think I've set up everything correctly but it's not working. I'm using macOS 11.5.2, Java edition server 1.17.1 I can connect to my own server using 127.0.0.1. My friends cannot access the server at same version using my public IP address

Here's the part where it's (supposed to) port forward:

*Port Forwarding Settings*
[image: Port Forwarding Settings - Screenshot]

*Minecraft Rule*
[image: Minecraft Rule - Screenshot]

I cannot put 0.0.0.0 on the source IP address because it shows invalid IP format. I can keep it blank.
[image: Can't keep 0.0.0.0 as source IP]

[image: Can keep it blank (current settings.]

I've not done anything to the network settings. Cannot put static ip setting as blank. I don't know what to do. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You need a static IP address which is local to your network. If you find this as confusing, better read more about port forwarding.

Comment: @ThatManiac I have edited your question, including displaying in-line images. Please review these changes and make any additional adjustments you wish.

Comment: The second screenshot mentions PON (Passive Optical Network) and shows options to get an IP automatically from the ISP, or manually enter an IP address your ISP has provided. I.e. this is the WAN interface (ISP connection) configuration page of a router. If this is what you connect to your ISP with, and they have *not* provided you a static IP (that'd be noted down on the contract, on a letter or at maybe in an email) you probably should leave it is. Or at minimum call your ISP and confirm the correct settings. Right now it's static but no IP configured => no connection.

Comment: Hello, I've not clicked Ok (there's an ok button below) and when i click that it shows "invalid IP address" I've set it to DHCP now.

Comment: Have you checked what's available in the "Select Application" drop-down box? That usually contains ready-made, working settings for common applications, often also for most common games... and this day and age I'd say Minecraft is fairly common... :-) If 0.0.0.0 isn't allowed but blank is, I'd test with that. After thinking a bit, I'd actually configure "Source IP" only when I wanted to allow access for a specific system but not everyone, for example allowing you and *only* you access my NAS I'd put your public IP as SourceIP.

Comment: Just remember... you're testing port forwarding on a router/firewall. You should test it by trying to access from outside, over the internet. Not knowing this device I can't say if testing with your phone from within your own network is valid.

Comment: In the Protocol drop-down, can you select TCP/UDP instead of just TCP? If not, make a second rule for the same ports but using UDP. [Source](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-set-up-a-public-minecraft-server-33c2da0bbc2)

Comment: [Here](https://www.portchecktool.com/)'s a tool to test if your port forwarding works. Also [make sure that the port is allowed in Windows Firewall](https://www.wikihow.com/Portforward-Minecraft).

Comment: [This](https://portforward.com/softwareguides/minecraft/portforward-minecraft.htm) says that you also have to forward UDP ports 19132-19133 and 25565 in addition to TCP 25565. Which of course means the same ports must be open in your system firewall as well.

Comment: Last screenshot, check the section that starts "The message which is from network side...". This makes your computer part of the DMZ (Demilitarized Zone), which isn't protected by the FW at all. Anyone can reach the PC with internal IP 192.198.1.6 just by pointing at your external IP address... any application, any port... I would disable this **_immediately_**.

Comment: Ok so to clarify:
1. It doesn't have anything related to games. It's only smtp, webserver, etc.
2. I ask my friend whether he can connect the server. The website said " Problem!  I could not see your service on (ip) on port (25565).
Reason: Connection timed out.". I also use macOS and firewall is disabled. There's also nothing in system preferences mentioning ports.
3. Yes I can but it didn't do anything
4. I'm trying to host a java edition server and it only requires port 25565
5. Ok i'll do that ASAP!

Comment: I'd suggest starting from scratch. First double-check everything's set up and running correctly. [Here](https://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Minecraft-Server-on-a-Mac)'s one instruction - I can't validate it. Do use static IP on the server. Next verify that you can play within your own network - that _must_ work first. If not, ask a new question about that. When that works, look again into port forwarding. I'd strongly recommend updating your question, starting with "I'm setting up a Minecraft Java server on MacOS (version?) following instructions in (link).

Comment: I can connect and play locally, but not over the internet. My friend tested it by (how exactly? Connecting with browser or Minecraft client? Versions?) and (results). Port forwarding is configured (screenshot of the last screen)."  You can update your current question, but remove unnecessary screenshots etc. - only the ones that show current situation are relevant. Or you can ask a new one. This is just to allow other community members to understand the situation without going through these extended commentaries - easier for them to pitch in.

Comment: I'd also contact my ISP and ask if they can help setting the internet part up. The more details you give and the more clear and accurate they are, the faster and better help you can expect to get. Until then I'd leave the port forwarding settings as they are in the last screenshot - they look correct to me. As you say, only the one TCP port should be sufficient. And because of what I said before I'd leave the Source IP now empty unless ISP tells me otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

The device's manual interestingly doesn't have any information how to configure port forwarding.

I don't have this router, so I can't say what's supposed to be on the Interface so I suppose that's the only available option, and thus correct.  This is what rest of it means:

- SourceIpAddress - the public IP provided by your ISP
- InternalHost - static internal IP address of the device providing the service - you can't forward to a dynamic IP, but providing a non-changing IP to a device using DHCP reservation should be sufficient
- StartPort - whatever you want to use to access the service from the outside
- EndPort - the port the device providing the service is listening to
- MappingName is just a name you give to know what the rule is doing

Comment: +1. I approve this edit. ;)

Comment: @Anaksunaman :-D

Comment: I did not understand the "providing non changing ip to DHCP reservation" thing. One router I configured didn't have static external ip yet the port forwarding worked. I'm not even sure if I'm telling about the same thing as I am very new to this. Thanks

Comment: I second @harrymc - you should read up a bit :-) Your router has a FW, and by configuring port forwarding you poke a hole to that FW to will allow traffic in. You have a RasPi with IP 192.168.0.10 running a web server, you need to configure your router to make it accessible by forwarding traffic on 80 and 443 to that IP. RasPi's is offline for a week, and you bring in a second computer. When you boot up the RasPi again, it now gets IP address 192.168.0.11, and the web server is inaccessible - so you don't want the IP to change. That's why you give it a static one, or do a reservation.

Comment: Remember, you don't need to configure port forwarding to allow outgoing traffic. You need it to allow incoming traffic.

Comment: Hello peregrino,  If I do not restart my computer and router, the ip will be the same right?

Comment: You *really* should read up so that you understand DHCP and port forwarding. You can't expect the community members to teach you. The very basics would be enough to tell you "yes, very likely".

Comment: If I'm configuring a static ip on my phone and input the computer's ip address, will that work?

Comment: There's absolutely no way for me or anyone else to answer that question with the information you've provided. Please update your original question - why exactly are you configuring port forwarding? What are you trying to achieve? Are your phone and computer connecting to the same SSID?

Comment: I've edited d the original post but the images come in links.

Comment: The way I read that is "direct all inbound traffic using port 25535 to server 192.198.1.6 port 25535". If your PC has that IP set static and it's actually listening on port 25535, anyone should now be able to connect to your MC server over the internet using that port. The IP address of the MC client shouldn't matter, and if you can ping your phone's IP from the PC it should also be able to connect, if the router allows Wi-Fi clients to talk directly to each other. If that doesn't work test changing the source IP to 0.0.0.0 - that stands for "all IP addresses".

Comment: ... and please do let me know... we might be creating the only available port forwarding manual for that box :-D

Comment: Edited with some more info. I don't know whether if it's useful or not.