# How to port forward from Genexis Platinum 4410 router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding

Router firmware version:  P4410-V2-1.39

Tried to follow the steps mentioned in this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/1415011/how-to-port-forward-on-genexis-platinum-4410?rq=1). Cant find the Virtual server configuration section. I dont know what I should do here. How do I port-forward if i cant find the option to portward in the first place?

screenshot of the app section in my router settings
[image]

Comment: As per the comment on the linked question "Most likely your ISP has installed customized firmware, that explicitly disables port forwarding. This is not unusual for residential lines provided by low-quality ISPs, as it reduces attack surface and thus support load on the ISP"

Comment: You should contact your ISP.